# Grails app fails on running, throws Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: maven, grails, dependencies

On `grails` command -

```
| Starting daemon.....
objc[12723]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1087804c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10af344e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

On running -

```
grails> run-app --verbose
| Compiling 5 source files
| Compiling 5 source files.....
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.injection.GrailsASTUtils.addEnhancedAnnotation(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/ast/ClassNode;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/ast/AnnotationNode;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.injection.GrailsASTUtils.addEnhancedAnnotation(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/ast/ClassNode;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/ast/AnnotationNode;
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerActionTransformer.getCodeToHandleAllowedMethods(ControllerActionTransformer.java:472)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerActionTransformer.wrapMethodBodyWithExceptionHandling(ControllerActionTransformer.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerActionTransformer.convertToMethodAction(ControllerActionTransformer.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerActionTransformer.processMethods(ControllerActionTransformer.java:248)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerActionTransformer.performInjectionOnAnnotatedClass(ControllerActionTransformer.java:203)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerActionTransformer.performInjection(ControllerActionTransformer.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.injection.GrailsAwareInjectionOperation.call(GrailsAwareInjectionOperation.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1047)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:583)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:561)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:517)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.runCompiler(Groovyc.java:1104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:1155)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.Grailsc.compile(Grailsc.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:770)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:319)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:264)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:203)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compile(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:298)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$compile$5.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compile(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:265)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compileAll(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:256)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$compileAll$4.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2_closure6_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:47)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2_closure6_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at _GrailsCompile.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy:68)
    at _GrailsCompile.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:46)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:342)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:952)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1131)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at 

...
...

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
| Error Error running script run-app --verbose: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
```

Grails version is 2.4.0. Maven version 3.3.9.

Grails BuildConfig.groovy file -

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true,jvmArgs: ['-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1']],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false,jvmArgs: ['-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1']],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false,jvmArgs: ['-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1']],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256,jvmArgs: ['-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1']]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'

        compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:$springVersion"

        // CW dependencies
        runtime 'com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2'
        compile 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.10'
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        provided ":tomcat:9.0.0.M4"
        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.0"
        compile ':cache:1.1.6'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.7"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.3" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.15"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.7.4"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Earlier, it was complaining in the `grails` command part, where it was asking for dependencies, which it was unable to download itself. That got resolved once I downloaded them manually by creating a separate maven project.

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: Java version 1.8.0_20.

Comment: The question indicates you are using Grails 2.4.  Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we support Java 8.

Comment: Oh right. I setup jdk 1.7 for the directory where I am going to run grails, using jenv. But I am not getting any output when I run the grails command. No errors. I tried doing a fresh setup of grails 2.4.0 but no success. I did an uninstall using sdkman - sdk uninstall and then reinstall, but it does not download a fresh copy. It shows - `Found a previously downloaded grails 2.4.0 archive. Not downloading it again...` It shows success, but again, no output on grails command.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I did a fresh setup of the project with Java 1.7, and still facing issue - kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320885/grails-2-4-0-legacy-app-throwing-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not getting any output when I run the grails command

You are probably missing JAVA_HOME

yes, I know that this is 2 years old question :)